# Install certification to acknowledge another server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

I need to install a .cer to my apache server in order to comunicate to another server.

Basically I have my server, x.x.x.100, this server has an script that uses SOAP to communicate to another server, x.x.x.200. The comunication is through https (e.g.: https://x.x.x.200/soap?wsdl) but my server is not connecting to the other server.

In the documentation of the other server it says that I need to install a .cer in order to be able to comunicate to that server (x.x.x.200).

How can I do that in a Linux server (LAMP stack)?

Comment: Is apache actually making the connection to the other server or is some other piece of software making that connection?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really simple to make warningless https certificates. First you need to be sure, if this is the problem. It can be tested by wget-ting any of the https urls of your second server. It will be OK, if your wget is willing to get https urls without the --no-chec-certificates option.

If it is ok, then your problem is not here. If not, you need to make a self-signed certificate, install the public + private key to your first server, install the certificate to your second server and finally put this in its allowed key repository.

You stay before a long journey. Good luck! :-)

Comment: When I try wget --no-check-certificates I get the following OpenSSL: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac. Unable to establish SSL connection.
Any Ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Then you have much bigger problems as a missing cert. Check the log on the server side.

Comment: It just says: EACCELERATOR(30389): PHP crashed on opline 22 of SoapClient() at file.php

Comment: The problem is not in your soap client, but in your apache & php on the server side. Make a systemupgrade/refresh, if it doesn't work, try to get an apache/php install from some other source.